# MobX not rerendering React component as used @computed is changed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

MobX appears to not be working for me.  I have essentially these two files:

```
@inject("apiDepo")
@observer
class Test extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return <div>{this.props.apiDepo.remoteNum}</div>
  }
}
```

.

```
// apiDepo.ts
class apiDepo {
  @observable private _remoteNum;

  @computed get remoteNum() {
    console.log("get")
    return this._remoteNum || (this.fetchRemoteNum() && undefined);
  }

  private async fetchRemoteNum() {
    const response = await someFuncThatRequestsARemoteNum();
    console.log("set")
    this._remoteNum = response.remoteNum || 0;
    console.log(this);
    console.log("remoteNum", this.remoteNum);
  }
}
```

The output to console of running this is

```
> "get"
> "set"
> { _remoteNum: 0, fetchRemoteNum() } // is missing this.remoteNum
> "remoteNum" undefined // should be 0
```

Followed by no more gets.

As far as I can tell, this is a pretty simple example of how MobX is supposed to work.  You get an observable, it get's updated, forceUpdate() should be called (but is not).

What I want to know is *Why might it not be working?*  Does anything seem off about the implementation above?  And if not, does anyone have any leads on why it's not working?

EDIT:  I do not have anything that overloads componentShouldUpdate except for @observer

EDIT 2: Added console.log(this.remoteNum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that makes problems is this here:

```
return this._remoteNum || (this.fetchRemoteNum() && undefined);
```

The reason is, that when _remoteNum equals 0, it's false (because it casts the number to a boolean. And 0 is interpreted as false). So it won't return the number, but call fetch again! You can easily see this behavior by returning a new number after each call:

```
const response = await new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
            window.setTimeout(() => resolve(this._remoteNum++), 1000);
})
```

To prevent this boolean casting, you need to explicitly compare that value.

So the solution is:

```
@observable _remoteNum: number;

@computed get remoteNum(): number {
    if(this._remoteNum != null) {
        return this._remoteNum;
    } else {
        this.fetchRemoteNum() && undefined;
    }
}

private async fetchRemoteNum() {
    const response = await new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
        window.setTimeout(() => resolve(0), 1000);
    })

    console.log('updated');

    this._remoteNum = response;
}
```

I would recommend to always use === or !== and not let javascript implicitly cast the value to boolean